# How to highlight element on a bottom bar in Android, without using Fragments

Tags: android, android-activity, bottombar

I'm developing an app, which has three activities; you can switch the activities using a bottom bar. However, whenever I switch the activity, the bottom bar highlights the first element, and not the element correspondent to the activity I chose.

That's what I want:

[image]

And that's what happens:

[image]

I could use fragments, but I have to re-create all my project; also, I method that I'm using is not working even if I change it in a fragment.

How can I resolve my problem without using fragments? How can I highlight the element in the bottom bar?

Thanks for your replies!

Comment: The links are broken. Please embed all necessary information in SO and don't use external links if possible.

Comment: @MrLeeh links are not broken its `i.stack.imgur.com` links that SO upload image there.. so I dont think its external link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code to `onResume()` of activity. So whenever activity started that item will be selected already.

```
mBottomNavigationView.getMenu().getItem(index).setChecked(true);
```

`index` refer to menu item number 0-2(Because you have three items). In your case for setting index should be 1 for setting.